# How to add a laravel's new packages to several projects in different folders by using composer?

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, image-uploading

i haven't got this able to work. I have been googled this for days so hopefully someone can help me or shed light for this.

I have installed Laravel by using composer and practiced programming a simple application. Then i wanted to carry on programming another application and i copied all the folders of my previous (very first) laravel project into another folder inside the htdocs folders. I am using XAMPP on windows.

Then i did the same and have four projects in different folders. I changed the original folder name of my very first laravel app in order to keep track of what i have been programming.

So now i am stuck in image uploading in another project. I downloaded the Intervention/image package by using Composer, it did well, I typed 
composer require intervention image
and it was installed successfully.

Then i ran into this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   (E_ERROR)  Class 'Image' not found

Then i thought that possibly composer installed it into my original laravel project. I have tested all my applications by calling this image class and i still get this error. Now i am lost, i don't know where the intervention/image package was installed :( I don't find a folder that is named intervention or something like that.

Tell me how i can find out where is composer pointing to or installing the new packages?

I have also tried configuring the intervention/image in all the projects i have according to this website: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation
And it says to add the following two lines in app/config/app.php

> "In the $providers array add the service providers for this package.
>
> ```
> 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
> ```
>
> Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.
>
> ```
> 'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' "
> ```

And i Have done that in all the applications and i get still another error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found
```

My code in the controller files looks like this so far:

```
//UPLOAD PICTURE
public function getUploadPicture(){
    return View::make('account.uploadpicture');
}

//POST función que sube la foto del usuario
public function postUploadPicture(){
    var_dump($image=Input::file('photo'));
    $image=Input::file('photo');
    var_dump($image->getRealPath());
    Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    die();
    return Redirect::route('account-upload-picture')
                    ->with('global','<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
                            ¡La foto se ha enviado exitosamente!</div>')
                    ->withInput();
}
```

So now i have three questions,

1. how do i get to know what the default directory is of composer?
2. How do i know where the Intervention/Image was installed?
3. how do i add another project so that it may be able to use the
   Intervention/image too as well as future projects?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the package to your composer file. In laravel's project root, open up the `composer.json` file and add `"intervention/image": "2.*",` to the `require` section of the json. Then run composer update to fetch the package.

Comment: Hello, i have opened that file and those requires are indeed there. I tried installing faker and i have the following: `{
    "require": {
        "intervention/image": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4"
    }
}` Nevertheless i still have problems. I want to know where is composer pointing these installations, to what project, since I have several projects in different directories. (Thanks to your answer, at least i know where intervention has been installed: `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\vendor`). Then how do i tell composer to direct to: `C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel01` project?

Comment: If you are using laravel, you can see that laravel automatically picks up the vendor autoloads with https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/autoload.php#L17. You can learn more about psr-0/psr-4 autoloading at http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/